# Starcraft 2 unit tester that works with the released version?

Tags: starcraft-2

There was a custom map that someone made during the beta that made testing various unit matchups very easy.  It was called TheUnitTester.  It still sort of works with the release version, but has lots of bugs.  does anyone know of an updated version of this map, or an equivalent?  (I just got wasted by a massive ball of stalkers, and I was wondering how many speedlings I would have needed to take it down, and whether a mix of speedlings and roaches would have been more bang for my buck, which i expect.

Comment: Adding as a comment instead of an answer because it's not answering the main question, but I would definitely say throwing some roaches and possibly some banelings in the mix would be better than only speedlings.

Comment: in case anyone's wondering, 34 speedlings just barely beat 12 stalkers.  32 speedlings lost. more than that crushed. YMMV of course, based on terrain and upgrades and micro and such.

Comment: FYI The Unit Tester is buggy but it works for me, I managed to test your scenario. I just had to manually build the spawning pool for the upgrade, but the game enables that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a map called [hardcounter](http://www.sc2mapster.com/maps/hardcounter/) that is similar. It's designed to be more like a game, but it has a sandbox mode that I've found useful for testing out different unit combinations.